# Query String Privacy with .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a website; mywebsite.com

I've recently created a new navigation for it and at the moment to see the new nav in comparison to the old nav you just add a query string at the end of ;

mywebsite.com?nav=new

This is all done in code behind in .net, I am fairly new to the whole environment and was wondering, without prior knowledge, would someone be able to find out this query string and see the new nav...assuming they are just not just a random person on a website, trying to guess different query strings etc..

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Google may have picked it up from somewhere and a person with no prior knowledge could access it via a google search without realising.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that, thanks, I suppose disallowing query strings in the robots.txt 'could' help on that side things.

Comment: _“Hope this makes sense.”_ – no really. If it was really important that no one found this URL prematurely - then you would not be doing this in the live system in the first place, but in the dedicated dev/staging environment, that has additional access restrictions in place (such as f.e. HTTP Auth) against unauthorized outside access.

Comment: I fear you've read between the lines, this was more of a exploritory question, this is all on my test environment and I was mearly wondering if i publish, what would happen in regards to my question posed.  Plus re-reading back my question, I wasn't too clear in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

If your page exists in the wild, then the query string may be discoverable simply by the fact (depending on browser configuration) it may show in external http logs and proxy logs, most commonly as the "referer" [sic] on resource fetches and hyperlinks to other pages *by the priveleged few users who are allowed to know about it*. Essentially: just by using your site against an isolated server, users can inadvertently leak this info.

Then you've got *conscious* leaking by people sharing links on twitter etc, or browser plugins that snag the url for whatever reason.

Nothing here is specific to .net or vb.net or anything else server-side, and relates **purely** to the nature of client-side http / html.

So... don't rely on it as a security mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciated!